# iOS: UITableView's header show on top of first row/section

Tags: ios, tableview, tableheader

I am trying to make the first row of my `UITableView` to be shown on top of the table's `tableHeaderView` property with some offset.

[image]

Any idea how to do this with a table view ?

Comment: Return two section and then return one row for section 1 and return rest of the row for section 2. First section header view make nil and second section  header view make as you wish.

Comment: This is the headerview of the table itself, not a section header.

Comment: You should use a tableView header for this purpose. (Note: this is not the same as a tableView section header). 
The `tableView`has a property `tableHeaderView`. Just set this property to the view you want to display on top of your tableView (for example in viewDidLoad).

Comment: @guybrushthreepwood pls see the screenshot to see what I mean

Comment: @Petar ok sorry, I got that wrong. Cant think of a clean way to do this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Eiko, what I tried to do with my other answer is potentially insecure and can lead to unforseen circumstances.

What I ended up doing eventually is creating a new separate `UIView` and positioning it in the appropriate place as a subview of the `UITableView` to mimick the behaviour of the tableView's tableViewHeader property.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted in a very trivial way:

`[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.tableView.tableHeaderView];`

Comment: This is dangerous. You are fiddling with something that you do not have under your control. You don't know about side effects, you don't know if or when the tableview might update its views, you don't know if it will run as expected in any other situation (i.e. even a minor .0.1 update might break it).

Comment: Have you got any other idea then ?

Comment: Not really.. I wonder what "offset" means in the case for scrollable tables. You might want to experiment with custom cells or section headers that mimic the tableHeader. Not exactly sure how scrolling will effect the different components, though - and if it was/is/will be consistent.